# How to get values from a dictionary in swift 4

Tags: swift, facebook, dictionary

I am developing an application with Swift 4 (Xcode 9).I sign in with Facebook and get information about my friends.
Here is my code :

```
func friends() {
    let params = ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, email, picture"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/taggable_friends", parameters: params).start { (connection, result , error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }
        print(result!)

        let info = result! as! [String : AnyObject]
        let info = result! as! [String : AnyObject]
        let Objet = (info as! [String : AnyObject])["data"]
        let nom = Objet!["first_name"] as! String
        print(nom)
        }
}
```

But i get them as a dictionary like this :

```
{
data =     (
            {
        "first_name" = Sameh;
        id = AaJjv05Upw5Ly78wKWir2jfuKn5nC1PrIIccIaYFs1wclQML5l3K1qQhDekAxmVBEx1gtYEOYG7ctOFI96bv4O5irNPMvGGF9T39XnPML5CzMw;
        "last_name" = "Ben Abdallah";
        picture =             {
            data =                 {
                height = 50;
                "is_silhouette" = 0;
                url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/28379127_1987965651456087_2667061843745873769_n.jpg?oh=eb4c37b135775fea526ff8158d9ded17&oe=5B2C3F91";
                width = 50;
            };
        };
    },
            {
        "first_name" = Dhouha;
        id = "AaJrJ_bKAeZZ8JXg9twhVV0HhngwK_pUYcTEQyfvxSBJAeFg4o7oeIu9VzXQ6es_MeA1oXVRPd_sFGCq0X3Z5pi29njT_58wn6iEX1sF98tRIA";
        "last_name" = Souidi;
        picture =             {
            data =                 {
                height = 50;
                "is_silhouette" = 0;
                url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/29339568_104531293722629_3382683098066976768_n.jpg?oh=d1e4a8a3616c63327d32db670657205a&oe=5B2F734E";
                width = 50;
            };
        };
    }
```

I can't get the values of the fields first_name, last_name, picture and id as String in order to be able to insert them into the database.
I get the error :

```
"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"
```

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Where's your attempt to get any values out of `result`?

Comment: I tried with this : let info = result! as! [String : AnyObject]
            let Objet = (info as! [String : AnyObject])["data"]
            let nom = Objet!["first_name"] as! String
            print(nom)                                                                                         But I get the error :   " unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value   "

Comment: All of that information needs to be in your question, not in comments.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right.

Comment: Then please edit your question and put in those details.

Comment: I edit my question.

Comment: Hope you are aware that you are allowed to use the info you get from this endpoint for tagging only. It is _not_ a way to “get all friends” for any other purpose.

Comment: Your edited question has now made my answer obsolete. That's not appropriate. You are now asking a completely different question. Given this, I am rolling back your question to what you originally asked. Your question about getting email is a whole new question.

Comment: I understand  what you mean. So am I permitted to ask that as a new question in Stackverflow?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a dictionary. The `data` key gives you an array of dictionaries.

You need to properly handle optionals and use the correct data types.

```
func friends() {
    let params = ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, email, picture"]
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/taggable_friends", parameters: params).start { (connection, result , error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else if let info = result as? [String: Any] {
            print(info)
            if let data = info["data"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                for object in data {
                    if let nom = object["first_name"] as? String {
                        print(nom)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Unexpected result: \(String(describing: result))")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get values  of the first friend. When I update the function to get information of each friend (for ... in...) I get an error. I want to  know how can I post my question : update this post or ask a new question ?

Comment: Update your question with specific details about your use of a loop and the errors you get.